# What do I need to set up a development environment for developing in C# & SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed, but that's about it.

I am not sure what else is needed to be installed in order to start going through the many C# (accessing SQL Server) available out there.

Tips and links to a step-by-step dev env setup instruction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So... You took a consulting job in a technology you don't know at all. Was that wise?

Comment: In addition to what others mentioned, you will need [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) just as demonstrated in [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJfYSZzZOP8). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have Visual Studio 2010,, you are done, it comes installed with a SQL compact library and an SQL express server. You are good to go.

For SQL server management you can download [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593)

Comment: Thanks! @scatmoi also mentioned a tool called SQL Server Management Studio. Is this needed? Where do I get one that matches my Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @NotSoSharp I added extra link to management studio

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server express will definitely help you.

In fact you need two basic thing:

1. visual Studio (you got!)
2. SQL Server. For most case, SQL server express will do the job.

Just do the full install, all tools should be included: [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Comment: Thanks! @scatmoi also mentioned a tool called SQL Server Management Studio. Is this needed? Where do I get one that matches my Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is the best tool to work with SQL Server. It doesn't need to match your Visual Studio, it's need to match your SQL server. 
Everything you need for SQL express is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763